# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python3

The code's below. And I get "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found".

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)"
values = {'q': 'python programming tutorials'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url = 'https://www.google.com/search'+data
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
resp_data = resp.read()
print(resp_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not adding `data` as a query parameter, indicated by adding a `?` after `/search`

Here is your code modified and working

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)"
values = {'q': 'python programming tutorials'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?'+data
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
resp_data = resp.read()
print(resp_data)
```

The actual difference being your `url`

```
>>> url
'https://www.google.com/searchq=python+programming+tutorials'
```

and my modified `url`

```
>>> url
'https://www.google.com/search?q=python+programming+tutorials'
```

There is no resource located at https://www.google.com/searchq and that is the reason you're getting

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found